# Replace text in a file

Tags: python

Its pretty simple, with  the small code bellow, i can read a file and match where i can find the musicStyle field and replace the value with something else and write the changes on the file.  Its a xml and i know that i could use lxml or other xml parser, but i want to keep using the re module because is nothing huge, its for my personal database of music collection.

```
import re

def replace(theFile):
    #for iLine in (line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(theFile,"w")):
        if iLine.find("musicStyle") >= 0:
            mpr = re.search(r'(.*>)(.*?)(<.*)', iLine, re.M|re.I)
            print mpr.group(2)
            # here goes the code to replace the mpr.group(2) 
            # should i use iLine.replace('rock','Metal') ?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    replace('c:\testfile.xml')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not simply use `re.sub`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary i could, but i dont know how to write the changes on the file.

Comment: I've added an answer.

Comment: Being "huge" is irrelevant, XML isn't a regular language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module if you're trying to modify the same file:

```
import fileinput
for iLine in filinput.input(r'c:\testfile.xml',inplace = True):
    if iLine.find("musicStyle") >= 0:
         mpr = re.search(r'(.*>)(.*?)(<.*)', iLine, re.M|re.I)
         #modify iLine here
    print iLine     #write the line to  the file
```

Note that when you're using windows paths always use raw string, otherwise this will happen:

```
>>> print 'c:\testfile.xml'
c:  estfile.xml            #'\t' converted to tab space

>>> print r'c:\testfile.xml'   #raw string works fine
c:\testfile.xml
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you, i was doing exactly the same thing, im adding my answer with what solved my problem but im marking yours as correct since it got me to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the best thing to do would be to write the output to a separate temporary file, then move the file in place of the original file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with:

```
import re

def replace(theFile):
    for line in fileinput.input(theFile,inplace=1):
        if line.find("musicStyle") >= 0:
           mpr = re.search(r'(.*>)(.*?)(<.*)', line, re.M|re.I)
           line = line.replace("rock","metal")
        print line,


if __name__ == '__main__':
    replace('c:\\testfile.xml')
```

i had to put a comma on **line** in order to avoid new lines on the file.

Thanks Ashwini for the direction.

Comment: You're still not using a raw string. :)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary i simplified the example in fact im passing the file from a loop over files on a directory :) . but i will fix it to not lead on error to others.